# How to create update query with QSqlQuery

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an update query in Python3/PyQt5.10/Sqlite . A select/insert query made the same way runs fine. Fields & corresponding record exist.

```
def updateRecords():

    theDict = {
        "Loc": "PyQt121",
        "BoekNr" : "dfdf",
        "BoekTitel" : "eeee",
        "BoekBedrag" : 999
    }
    theFilter = " WHERE Loc = 'PyQt'"

    query = QSqlQuery()
    columns = ', '.join(pDict.keys())
    placeholders = ':'+', :'.join(pDict.keys())

    sql = 'UPDATE  %s SET (%s) VALUES (%s)  %s' % (pTable, columns, placeholders, pFilter)      

    query.prepare(sql)

    for key, value in pDict.items():
        query.bindValue(":"+key, value)
    print (sql)
    query.exec_()
    print(query.lastError().databaseText())
    return query.numRowsAffected()
```

The sql generated is UPDATE  tempbooks SET (Loc, BoekNr, BoekTitel, BoekBedrag) VALUES (:Loc, :BoekNr, :BoekTitel, :BoekBedrag)   WHERE Loc = 'PyQt'. 
query.lastError().databaseText()) give me "No Query" and updated rows is -1.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for an update query:

```
UPDATE tablename
set col1 = val1,
col2 = val2,
col3 = val3
WHERE condition
```

Probably `query.prepare(sql)` is returning False because of invalid syntax.